# Scroll screen using string instructions in assembly language 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, vga

I had a task to scroll screen using string instructions. My code doesn't work much fine and I cannot figure out the problem. The code prints A-Y on screen and then it should scroll first row to second and so on but it rather copies the first row and so on.

```
org 100h

.DATA

ARRAY1 DW 80 DUP(0)

.CODE                  

MOV CX,25           
MOV AX,0XB800
MOV ES,AX
MOV DI,0
MOV AH,0X07
MOV AL,41H

L:
MOV BX,CX
MOV CX,80
REP STOSW
INC AL

MOV AX,DS
MOV ES,AX
LEA DI,ARRAY1

MOV AX,0XB800
MOV DS,AX
MOV CX,80
CLD 
REP MOVSW

MOV CX,25
MOV DI,160

MOV SI,0

K:
MOV BX,CX
MOV AX,0XB800
MOV ES,AX

MOV CX,80
CLD
REP MOVSW
ADD DI,160
CMP DI,3840
JE EXIT
ADD SI,160
JMP K

EXIT: ret
```

Comment: Comment your code especially if you want others to help and learn to use a debugger. That said, if I understand your code you first copy row 1 to row 2 and then try to copy row 2 to row 3 but of course you have already overwritten row 2. You should run that copy backwards.

Comment: @Jester there is a MOVS instruction so it should not copy the rows and DS and ES both point to VGA memory (except for copying first row to array).

Comment: Your `REP MOVSW` loop at `K` copies rows (in vga memory) as I said.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 problems in your code:

- You forgot to write `mov si,0` in the part that copies from the screen into the *Array1* buffer.
- You should start at the bottom of the screen to scroll the way you indicated (@Jester already pointed this out). This simple code will do the trick:

  ```
  mov AX, 0XB800
  mov es, ax
  mov ds, ax
  mov di, 3840      ;Address of 25th row
  cld
  K:
  lea si, [di-160]  ;Address of row above
  mov cx, 80
  rep movsw
  sub di, 320
  jne K             ;DI=0 is end
  ```